# mssql and mysql case sensitive like

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-like

I should select all rows where a specific field starts with 'z' but not with 'Z' and the query should work both with mysql and mssql.

I can write the query separated for mssql and mysql, but I can't convert it to a unique query to work with both database.

I don't know if it is possible at all. Any idea?

Comment: Show us your queries

Comment: Both seem to be controlled by the collation on the Table/Field.

Comment: Dale: For mysql: select fieldname from tablename where fieldname like binary 'z%'
For mssql: select fieldname  from tablename 
where fieldname collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS like 'z%'


Now you have the queries, can you give me the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use proper `collation`. For example `_BIN` or Case Sensitive. You can find supported collations from following query.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()   
WHERE name LIKE 'sql%latin%CS%' or name like '%BIN';
```

and query like this

```
select * from dbo.Categories
where CategoryName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS like 'be%'
```

Comment: Dear Alex,
Thanks for your answer, but how do I make a unique query to run both in mysql and mssql?